# How to use Regex on String in XQuery

Tags: xml, rss, xquery

I'm trying to create a simple XML out of an rss which I get online. The only problem I got is that when I ask for the link, some of the rss have like "www.page.com/old-something/www.page.com/.." so crearly the link won't work unless I can cut the first "www.page.." from the link, so my code goes as follows:
`let $itemLink :=string-afger($items/link, 'www.wantedpage*')`
where `$items` is the node of the Item.

I keep getting the error "Unknown system function" for which I don't know if it's  because I'm using the function incorrectly or not declaring the function namespace or it is something else.

Comment: Well, there's no function called string-afger(), and it that wasn't what you intended, you need to get better at checking what you type.

Comment: I tiped it incorrectly in this post but string-after() doesn't exist either, fortunatelly, the selected answer solved the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The name of the function you want is `fn:substring-after`.